# SCCM 2012 Client Auto-remediation breaks client

Tags: windows-7, sccm-2012

Our environment is running SCCM 2012 SP1 CU2.  Our workstation base is 99% Windows 7, most of which are 64 bit.

This post ([link](http://trevorsullivan.net/2012/11/21/configmgr-2012-ccmeval-exe-causing-client-corruption/)) shows details similar to what is going on.

Basically, something goes wrong (doesn't matter what - I can find no pattern) and ccmeval decides to remediate the client.  Unfortunately, it launches ccmsetup.exe twice, which FUBAR's the client for sure, and seems to be able to do damage to WMI in some cases.

It is not related to WMF 3 like the article above states.  My workstation has WMF 3 and does not auto-remediate.  Rather. anytime that a remediation is triggered, it breaks the client.

I know I can just turn off auto-remediation, thereby creating more work for my team, but saving some headaches.

So here's my question - **has anyone run into this behavior and figured out what was going wrong?**

Further, **were you able to fix it?  If so, how (in your environment)?**

I'm hoping to avoid a call to MS, but I would really like to know what is wrong and if there is a fix for it.  Looked at SCCM 2012 R2 docs and don't see anything that looks a fix.

Comment: Your workstation has WMF 3 and does *not* autoremediate, what happens if you manually ran the autoremediation, does it break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up calling Microsoft.  While I was working with them, which took a while, we upgraded to R2.  The upgrade fixed the issue.  So the moral of the story is, if you can, migrate to R2.